# Operator overloading - how can i change objects place?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have two classes.

```
Inch class:

class Inch{
private:
    double inches;

public:
    Inch() : inches(0) {}
    Inch(double i) { inches=i; }
    Inch operator+ (const Meter& m);
    void out(){ cout << "Inch:" << inches << "\n";  }
    double getInches() const { return inches; }
};
```

and Meter class

```
class Meter{
private:
    double meter;

public:
    Meter() : meter(0) {}
    Meter(double m) { meter=m; }
    Meter operator+ (const Inch& i);
    void out(){ cout << "Meter:" << meter;  }
    double getMeter() const { return meter; }
};
```

these are two non inline operator + functions

```
Meter Meter :: operator+ (const Inch& i){
    { return Meter(meter /  0.0254 + i.getInches()); }
}

Inch Inch :: operator+ (const Meter& m){
    { return Inch(m.getMeter() + inches * 0.0254); }
}
```

This is my main and compiles. There's no problem.

```
int main() {

    Inch i(6.4),
         resultInch;

    Meter m(14),
         resultMeter;


    i.out();
    m.out();


resultMeter = m + i;
     resultMeter.out();

     resultInch = i + m;
          resultInch.out();


    return 0;
}
```

what i want to do is to change is the place i + m in

```
 resultInch = i + m;
      resultInch.out();
```

i want to add these two like that

```
resultInch = m + i;
          resultInch.out();
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Then you should make both return an `Inch`. In my opinion, it makes no sense to have `inch + metre` return an `Inch` and `metre + inch` return a `Metre`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add converting constructors:

```
Inch(Meter const & m) : inches(m.getMeter() * 100.0 / 2.54) { }

Meter(Inch const & i) : meters(i.getInches() * 2.54 / 100.0) { }
```

Comment: when i put these i get this error : no match for no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘i * 2.54000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625e+0’ and same error with Meter

Comment: 14.1626 should be the correct answers for meter sum. but result is 21952 why .d

Comment: @mertmetin: Because your code is wrong? Check again how you create the results of those additions...

Comment: @KerrekSB why are you allowed to write `inches(m.getMeter() * 100.0 / 2.54)`, while `inches` is a member for your class `Inch` ?

Comment: @antitrust: It's a constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

You can make global addition operators that take 2 arguments

```
Inch operator+(const Meter& m, const Inch& i)
```

Comment: @mertmetin: He said a *global* addition operator, not a member function.